# Summing categories by just crossing off in a column

Tags: google-sheets

```
WHAT  | AMNT | CATEGORY
      |      | Cat1 | Cat2 | Cat3 
----------------------------------
Food  | 32   |  x   |      |       
Pants | 19   |      |  x   |        
Phone | 10   |      |  x   |        
Pizza | 93   |      |      |  x    
Car   | 20   |  x   |      |        
----------------------------------
SUM   |      | 52   | 29   | 93     
----------------------------------
```

Can this be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly shorter:

```
=sumif(C4:C8,"x",$B4:$B8)
```

Presumably in C10 and copied across to E10.

You may require `;`s in place of `,`s.

Answer (score 0):

So, Try,

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$6,C2:C6="x")
```

Drag fill to the right.

Edit: Here's a complicated single cell formula without the need to drag fill:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE($B$2:$B$6*(C2:E6="x")),ROW(B2:B6)^0)))
```